# Transitive closure of $p=\{(1,3),(2,1),(3,2),(4,1)\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

What is the transitive closure of the relation $p$? I thought it would just be $t=p \cup p^2$.
But in the solution I have, there is also $p^3$. Why is this so? What I showed is already the smallest transitive set!

Comment: $p\cup p^2$ contains $(4,1)$ and $(1,2)$ but not $(4,2)$, so it is not a transitive relation.

Comment: Oh I missed the fact that adding all the new elements of $p^2$, there could be other  _relations_ $(a,b)\in t$ and $(b,c) \in t$ and not $(a,c) \in t$ hence resulting in a non transitive set! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: if $R$ is a relation then $S:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}R^n$ is its transitive closure.

If $T$ is a transitive relation with $R\subseteq T$ then with induction it can be shown that $R^n\subseteq T$ for each  $n\in\{1,2,\dots\}$, so that $S\subseteq T$.

Conversely it can be shown that $S$ is a transitive relation with $R\subseteq S$.

Comment: The first part was already clear! The second part is a bit new.. you mean that there exists a transitive set $T$ for which $R^n \subseteq T$ and $T \subseteq R^n$ showing that $R^n$ is also transitive?

Comment: No, $R^n$ is not necessarily transitive. I am saying that $S$ defined like this will be a subset of **any** transitive relation $T$ that contains $R$. This means that $S$ - if it is a transitive itself and contains $R$ (and this is remarked in "Conversely...") - must be the **smallest** transitive relation that contains $R$, i.e. must be the transitive closure of $R$.

Comment: Ah ok! I understand now